# Database Development - General Structure and Planning

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I'm about to start a fresh project and I'm good on normalization of the data. My question is the business I'm working for has a number of tables on MS Sql Server and some version of Oracle. Access to create temporary or even use temporary tables may be limited. We might be able to setup our own tables but chances are 50/50. The approach taken in the past has been to create temporary tables as needed for data dumps into MS Access.

If I can edit / create tables on the SQL server then I'm good, but if not I was thinking about setting up one of the spare machines as a MySQL or MS Sql Express server rather than using Access as a number of these types of projects have been completed in the past and push towards a gig in size due to the amount of data downloaded for preparing reports. Would this be a reasonable approach if I'm locked out of MS Sql server or Oracle? What would you do if your hands were tied in a similar fashion?

To provide a little more insight here, the data dumps are often used to build dozens of excel reports (mostly charts). I was thinking if I can use the MS Sql or Oracle to do all the work via triggers / stored procedures / etc. then perhaps I can eliminate the need for Access and just download the data via VBA using Excel only to reduce the amount of time it takes to build the reports.

Maybe I can use an ORM and some kind of VB.net code rather than excel to build the charts faster?

I'm open to suggestions, let me know what you all think and any questions I'll try to answer the best I can

Comment: Have you considered using SSRS?

Comment: I can barely tell what's being asked here... I have 2 points though 1GB Excel files do not work well. Secondly, "What would you do if your hands were tied in a similar fashion?", my general strategy has been to untie my hands and argue until people cave. If you're not being given the correct tools for the job then you can't do it properly. If you work for a decent company then explaining this rationally should work.

Comment: Sorry Ben I guess being clear in this situation is difficult and I should have written it up in word then edit. No Gangreen I haven't looked at much regarding SSRS. That looks like a great piece to the puzzle that might come in handy. I'll check it out, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although setting up a PC with something like SQL Server Express or MySQL often *sounds* like a great idea, I strongly suggest that you get the backing of your boss before doing something of this nature.  Installing unapproved software on inappropriate/unmaintained workstations is often frowned upon with extreme prejudice.  Were I to do this at my current place of employment I'm confident I'd be looking for a job as soon as it was uncovered.  I completely agree that just about anything is better than MS Access - however, supporting an architecture such as the one you describe, at least temporarily until you can find a better gig, is probably better than unemployment.  YMMV.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for the response. They are OK with improvising, we have a half dozen boxes ready to do whatever we want with them. It's all just patch work until the big boys can allocate resources to building a real solution. I'd like to make the patch work as portable as possible so there's less impact to the users down the road. Thanks for your insight and opinions!

Comment: I'll go ahead an accept this answer to close this out, looked at some SSRS stuff and BIRT looks like a good option. I can write up a Java front end and build reports off the same app with that. The current setup downloading data to access, dumping it to dozens of tabs in excel, then running vba scripts for several hours building charts is something I'd like to avoid if possible and a Java app with BIRT might work. I'll keep digging to see what else I can find. I appreciate the information from all !

Answer (score 0):

Actually the most easy solution here would be to continue to use access as a front end, and simply link to the tables on the particular server database system in question.  That way you save all the money time and resources of having to pull down and build temporary local tables.

The end result is you get to continue to use Access as a great RAD tool, but enjoy the benefits of the security, performance and scalability of the server based system in question.